# Split Array into Multiple Strings of 100 Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

So I've got an array that has thousands of values. The delimiter is the same and the content is all numbers. It's a simple array.

Example..

```
[491353764,202825540,338196858]
```

Imagine that is 15000 values. I need to split the array into multiple groups of 100 strings.

I got the first 100 fine using this:

```
ids = ids.toString();
ids = ids.split(',', 100);
console.log(ids.toString());
```

I know this is basic stuff, but I couldn't find anything that would allow me to split it multiple times into groups. Am I focusing on the wrong thing thinking some version of `split` will do the job? Do I need to put it through a loop?

Comment: Are your numbers in an array or a delimited string?

Comment: Do you convert the array to a String on purpose? You could extract the first 100 elements by doing `.slice(0,100)` which will a. return a new array with the first 100 elements and b. remove those 100 from the original array

Comment: @SahilMuthoo The numbers are in that array but have to be converted to groups of 100 strings for the next call.

Comment: @Brandon: Convert them to strings *after* `slice`ing the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to store the groups of 100 in another Array...

```
var ids = [/* your large array of numbers */];

var array_of_sets = [];

while( ids.length ) {
    array_of_sets.push( ids.splice(0, 100) );
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/rP2Kq/1/

Comment: Storing the 100 in another group of 100 is fine since. I can just convert it to a string from there. Should `(id.splice(0,10) );` be 100 instead?

Comment: @Brandon: Yeah, I already updated. That was for my demo that I added, but forgot to change it back to 100 at first.

Comment: ...and if you actually want the result to be strings, then do it in the `while` loop. `array_of_sets.push( ids.splice(0, 100).toString() );`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Then, I can loop through the `array_of_sets` to make the next call.

Comment: @Brandon: Yes, you can loop over that Array to access each sub-group.

Comment: array_of_sets.push( String(ids.splice(0, 100)) )

Comment: @kennebec: Yep, that would work too, or even just `ids.splice(0, 100) + ''`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = [...];

var splitIds = [];
var splitSize = 100;

for (var j = 0; j < ids.length; j += splitSize) {
    splitIds.push(ids.slice(j, j + splitSize));
}
```